# What string functions can i add instead of some code sequences?

Tags: c, string

In this program I have to use as many string functions as possible. I used strlen, tolower. What other string functions can I add instead of some code sequences? I tried to add strcmp to compare but I did not succeed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

bool palindrom(char str[])
{
    int l = 0, h = strlen(str) - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i <= h; i++)
        str[i] = tolower(str[i]);

    while (l <= h) {
        if (!(str[l] >= 'a' && str[l] <= 'z'))
            l++;

        else if (!(str[h] >= 'a' && str[h] <= 'z'))
            h--;

        else if (str[l] == str[h])
            l++, h--;

        else
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    char str[100];
    printf("Introduceti sirul : ");
    scanf("%[^\n]",str);

    if (palindrom(str))
        printf("Propozitia este palindrom.");
    else
        printf("Propozitia nu este palindrom.");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `strlen` is not a string function, what is it? I guess you could say that `tolower` is a character function, but some would probably classify it as a string function, too.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

- `fgets` to read the string.

  - Sub suggestion: `iscntrl` to check for control characters, like newline, in the string
- `puts` to print strings that should have a newline at the end.

```c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

bool palindrom(char str[]) {

    // Convert to lowercase and get a pointer to the end in one go.
    // (You don't actually need the string length)
    // Note: You should convert to unsigned char before using ctype.h functions:
    char* end = str;
    for(;!iscntrl((unsigned char)*end); ++end) {
        *end = tolower((unsigned char)*end);
    }

    // terminate at the first control char which is probably newline
    // you get when using `fgets`:
    *end = '\0';

    // loop until the pointers meet:
    for(; str < end--; ++str) {
        // return false if they are not pointing at equal letters:
        if(*str != *end) return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int main() {
    char str[100];
    printf("Introduceti sirul : ");

    // Use fgets:
    if(fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)) {
        if(palindrom(str))
            puts("Propozitia este palindrom.");    // use puts
        else
            puts("Propozitia nu este palindrom."); // use puts
    }
}
```